# Conjugates in integrals

Tags: integration, operator-algebras

Is it always true that $\int f(x)^*M^\dagger Mf(x) dx=\int (Mf(x))^*(Mf(x)) dx$? where $M$ is an operator. If so, is there a simple proof that this is so? THanks.

Comment: $$\langle M^\dagger (M f),f\rangle=\langle Mf,(M^\dagger)^\dagger f\rangle=\langle Mf,Mf\rangle ?$$

Comment: @anon: Thanks! Is there a proof that uses integration directly?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You *have* to use the definition of the [adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) or you can't prove it, and beyond that nothing is necessary. This identity holds more generally for any inner product, whatever form it takes.

Comment: More specifically, anon's argument is essentially the same as showing that the _integrand_ is the in both integrals for all $x$. Then naturally the integration will yield the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator [Hermitian adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) $X^\dagger$ is defined to be the operator such that $\langle X \circ,\bullet\rangle=\langle\circ,X^\dagger\bullet\rangle$ for any two appropriate inputs $\circ,\bullet$. The conjugate symmetry of the [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) yields $$\langle X \circ,\bullet\rangle=\langle\circ,X^\dagger\bullet\rangle=\langle X^\dagger\bullet,\circ\rangle^*=\langle\bullet,(X^\dagger)^\dagger\circ\rangle^*=\langle (X^\dagger)^\dagger\circ,\bullet\rangle\quad\forall\circ,\bullet$$
$$\implies X=(X^\dagger)^\dagger.$$

Therefore $\langle M^\dagger (M f),f\rangle=\langle Mf,(M^\dagger)^\dagger f\rangle=\langle Mf,Mf\rangle$, which proves the identity after specializing the inner product to $\langle f,g\rangle=\int fg^*d\mu$. This fact goes beyond just integration as it applies to arbitrary inner products and can only be derived by using the definition of the adjoint ${}^\dagger$, after which nothing is really necessary. For specific types of operators and function spaces the identity may be check-able using by-parts integration. (For example, $M=d/dx$ for vanishing boundary conditions.)